# How to remove backface reflections in transparent EEVEE object?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

I am trying to make a glass "shell" in EEVEE for an object that is inside. In this example, I place Suzanne with an emission shader inside a *should be* transparent glass icosphere, which also has some roughness bump texture on it for clarity (shown later).

[image]

However, as you can see, some weird backface conflicts show up. I have enabled "show backface" in the material settings, without which the monkey cannot be seen at all. Now, I am aware of the trick to mix geometry and light path nodes in, and the result is shown below.

[image]

At the first glance, this is precisely what I needed. But when analyzed up close, it can be seen that the faces that I am observing are actually in the back:

[image]

What I would like instead, is to see the bumpy glass texture in the front and dark glass texture in the back. Answering the question "why?": because I would like to make a spin animation, and during this spin, it can be seen that the monkey is spinning in one direction, and the sphere is seemingly spinning in the other because you can only see the backfaces, not the front ones.

In a nutshell: How do I make a glass shell that is semi-transparent and bumpy in the front, and opaque-black in the back?

Comment: 'backfacing' means the other side of the face, not facing away from the camera.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this as your "glass" shader for the IcoSphere:

[image: IcoSphere]

Comment: aside: that's an interesting theme you're using.  Your own?

Comment: Ya. Custom since 2.8 - lemon lime, baby.